# Вопрос по NS серверу для домена

Tags: ip, dns, bind9

Задача такова.
Мне нужно чтобы на внешних доменах моих клиентов (klient.ru) отображался некоторый контент моего сервера example.ru.

Клиент прописывает в настройках своего домена ns1.example.ru и ns2.example.ru, которые я так понимаю должны отдавать IP моего сервера ХХ.ХХ.ХХ.ХХ.

Вопрос, как это лучше реализовать?

1. Найти бесплатыне/платные сервисы в интренете? Если таковые есть, подскажите?
2. Купить выделеный сервер и на нем настроить bind9. Если да, тогда помогите с конфигом.

Вариант с klient.ru CNAME example.ru конечно работает но не совсем подходит.

P.S. Кстати, а зачем прописывают не менее 2 ns серверов?

Comment: Ну клиенту никто не мешает просто в своем домене прописать A запись с вашим ip. С другой стороны, если он услугу DNS ни у кого не получает, тогда да - его NS должны указать на DNS сервера которые поддержат его зону. Обычно это проблема владельца домена - где будут его dns. Такая услуча обычно есть у регистраторов домена. А 2 NS пишутся для надежности, что бы если один dns лег домен продолжал жить

Comment: IP может менятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как именно реализовывать - выбор за вами.
В интернете как я понял довольно много бесплатных DNS серверов. Их список есть например в статье на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/203292/). Приведу несколько из них на случай если ссылка перестанет работать:

```
http://pdd.yandex.ru/
http://cloudflare.com/
https://dns.he.net/
https://www.dnsever.com/
```

Никогда бесплатными DNS (так же как и платными) не пользовался так что конкретно по ним ничего сказать не могу. У меня всегда свои DNS сервера были.

С учетом того, что Ваш IP может меняться и просить при этом прописать в своих DNS его не удобно, конечно лучше что бы NS записи домена клиента указывали на вас (ну или ваш бесплатный dns). С другой стороны, у клиентов, владеющих доменом может появляться законное желание создать на нем поддомены, настроить почтовый сервер для своего имени. И если DNS ваши, эти возможности вы сами должны будете обеспечить клиентам.

2 NS сервера - это в принципе совершенно правильное требование всех регистраторов имен и системы DNS в целом. оно обеспечивает отказоустойчивость доменного имени при сбоях на DNS серверах. Поэтому обычно основным требованиям к этим NS выступает то, что бы они были из отдельных подсетей. Если вы выберите вариант с размещением основного DNS сервера у себя, то для вторичного вполне можете найти какой нибудь бесплатный.

Каким бы образом не настраивался DNS, на вашем сервере или на сторонних, вам все равно придется прописывать свой IP в каждом домене по отдельности. Если клиентов много, а ip меняется часто - это может быть утомительно. Со своим DNS это возможно проще сделать т.к. можно все типовые домены описать одним конфигурационным файлом и отдельными файлами только тех клиентов, кому потребуются особые записи (поддомены, почта). Хотя судя по упоминаниям в указанной выше статье на хабре у некоторых бесплатных DNS есть API или DDNS, а следовательно можно настроить автоматическое обновление зон.

Если будете поднимать свой DNS ничего сложного в настройке нет, гугл по запросу "bind конфиг" выдает хорошие ссылки. Будут конкретные вопросы по настройке - задавайте вопросы

Немного подробностей как работает DNS: Мы вбиваем в браузер адрес yandex.ru. Мы еще не заходили туда в недавнее время и наш компьютер не знает по какому IP расположен этот сервер. Наш компьютер посылает запрос на DNS сервер провайдера или другой, указанный в настройках.

Что делает DNS сервер что бы ответить нам: Пытается узнать у кого можно спросить о доменах заны RU. Посылает запрос на корневые сервера интернета, те сообщают ему что они знают зону RU, а обслуживают ее NS сервера с такими адресами. Наш DNS сервер идет по указанным NS на сервера зоны RU. И спрашивает у них "как найти yandex.ru", на что сервера зоны RU отвечают:

```
yandex.ru.              12444   IN      NS      ns2.yandex.ru.
yandex.ru.              12444   IN      NS      ns1.yandex.ru.
ns1.yandex.ru.          12444   IN      A       213.180.193.1
ns2.yandex.ru.          12444   IN      A       93.158.134.1
```

Более никакой информации о yandex.ru у них нет и быть не может. Их задача дать нам только адреса NS серверов, которые смогут ответить на наш вопрос. А что бы наш браузер смог перейти по адресу yandex.ru наш компьютер должен получить `A` запись для этого имени. Такая запись есть только в DNS самого яндекса, поэтому мы шлем запрос например на ns1.yandex.ru (его ip нам сообщили): "Дай нам A запись для имени yandex.ru", на что он отвечает уже IP адресами которые нам и были нужны. Если же мы хотим послать почту на ящик `bla-bla@yandex.ru`, то почтовый сервер будет получать `MX` запись для домена yandex.ru. И опять же - регистратор домена в зоне RU ничего не знает о наших MX, обращение всегда идет до конечного DNS сервера поддерживающего зону.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. По поводу поддоменов исключено, а вот по поводу MX, пусть указывает, причем тут ns? или я что то путаю.

Comment: по поводу конфига bind, да инфы в гугле много, но я не могу понять сам механизм работы. Сервер поднял на ubuntu, все работает, а вот тут завис. Может правда обойтись klient.ru CNAME example.ru и не мучаться

Comment: мне по сути надо чтобы отдавался IP адрес example.ru и все

Comment: Дописал в ответ алгоритм работы DNS. Из него становится ясно, что у регистратора имен могут хранится только NS записи. MX записи можно прописать только на том DNS сервере который непосредственно поддерживает наш домен. И если клиент указывает у регистратора твои NS -сервера, то MX для клиента в зону прописывать придется тебе

Comment: В принципе CNAME примерно для таких вещей и сделан, да, конечно чуть дольше будет обрабатываться запрос, потому как сначала запросят тот домен, потом пойдут резолвить твой example.ru